# Convergence and limit of a sequence $x_n=1+\frac{x^2_{n-1}}{2},n\ge2,x_1=\frac{3}{8}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{x^2_n-2x_n+2}{2}>0$

sequence is increasing.

I don't know how to prove that it is bounded. Limit should be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Er...how could the limit be $1/2$, all of the terms except for the first one are at least $1$. In fact $F(x)=1+x^2/2$ has no real fixed point (the quadratic formula says the fixed points are $1 \pm i$), so there can be no finite limit. Do you have some minor typo? For instance this could have limit $1/2$ if it were $x_n=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{x_{n-1}^2}{2}$.

Comment: Maybe it is a mistake in my book's solution.